# Angular2 binding error "Cannot read property 'size' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, binding, ngfor

I'm trying to clone https://imageresize.org/ for practicing Angular 5. 
However, i'm facing a problem which prevents me from binding the value from typescript file to html.

Here is the input:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" autocomplete="off" style="display: none" id="input" draggable="true" (change)='changeInput()' multiple>
```

I'm also using xkeshi's image compressor (https://github.com/xkeshi/image-compressor) to compress the image:

```
changeInput() {
    this.img = <HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector('img,#image');
    this.files = (<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('input[type=file],#input')).files
    this.inputFlag = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      var imageCompressor = new ImageCompressor;
      imageCompressor.compress(this.files[i],{
        quality: .4
      }).then((result)=>{
        this.results[i] = result;
        this.resultSize = result.size;
        this.sizeRound = `${Math.round(100 - this.resultSize * 100 / this.fileSize)}%`;
      })
    }
  }
```

results is an array of Blob to get the value of "result" in a loop:

```
results: Blob[] = [];
```

HTML binding:

```
<tr *ngFor ="let file of files, let i = index">
                  <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{file.name.slice(0,7)}}</td>
                  <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{status}}</td>
                  <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center"></td>
                  <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{file.size}}</td>
              <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{results[i].size}}</td>
              <td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{sizeRound}}</td>
            </tr>
```

The error i get:
[a printscreen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6ovb.png)
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Thank you.
p/s: sorry for my English, i'm not a native speaker

Comment: What does your `files` array containes?

Comment: check what you have in 'this.files', if it is empty 'return false'.

Comment: I'm getting the error in the results[] array, 'files' is a FileList type that holds the values of the input files, and it works fine for now

Comment: have you tried to set `results` in `files` model like this: `this.files[i].results = result;` And in your html `{{file?.results.size}}`. Does this help you?????

Comment: @Sanoj_V i can't set `this.files[i].results = result` because results does not belong to type of files

Comment: @hrtlkr29 Ok, can you show `results` data.

Comment: @Sanoj_V https://ibb.co/dtG3gT here is the data

Answer (score 0):

As for as I understand, angular starts putting values as soon a component launches when the value might not be available.
So either size really does not exist on the object or its value is not available at the moment.

Try using optional values:

```
<td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{file?.size}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the 'file' is working just fine. The error i'm getting is in this line:

    `<td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{results[i].size}}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional operator to first check if the array != null before trying to access it.

```
<td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{results ? results[i]?.size : null}}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it only stop the browser from raising errors. Do you have any idea why the value of results is undefined in this case? Because if i console.log it in typescript file, there is still a value.

Comment: can you put a screenshot of the console.log?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of async issue in Angular, "results" is not yet derived as you expect.

```
<td style="height: 30px"  class="text-center">{{results ? results[i]?.size : null}}</td>
```

Also in the component, call the results explicitly through some method like below.

```
changeInput() {
    this.img = <HTMLImageElement>document.querySelector('img,#image');
    this.files = (<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('input[type=file],#input')).files
    this.inputFlag = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      var imageCompressor = new ImageCompressor;
      imageCompressor.compress(this.files[i],{
        quality: .4
      }).then((result)=>{
        //this.results[i] = result;
        this.refreshResults(i, result);
        console.log(this.results);
        this.resultSize = result.size;
        this.sizeRound = `${Math.round(100 - this.resultSize * 100 / this.fileSize)}%`;
      })
    }
  }

refreshResults(index, result) {
    this.results[index] = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, imo i'm facing some async issue tbh, but i don't know how to fix it atm. However, where is the "result" from refreshResults method comes from? It should be 
`refreshResults(index,result) {
    this.results[index] = result;
}`

right?

Comment: and in changeInput:

     `console.log(this.refreshResults(i,result));`
However, this will console out an "undefined" value

Comment: Yes you need to pass the result also as an argument. Just console.log this.results[index] after assigning the result to this.results[index]. This should work fine. Edited my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you, but somehow the html still can't get the value of results :(